# Tornado and Autobahn-python listening on the same port

Tags: python, tornado, autobahn, python-asyncio, wamp-protocol

Recently I started a small personal project. It's a realtime web system based on asyncio and autobahn-python. However I also would like to serve some static files via HTTP and do it from the same process. My HTTP server is Tornado sitting on top of asyncio event loop and everything works perfectly fine except that I have to start tornado and autobahn handlers on different ports. Here is a stripped down version of what I currently have:

```
import six
import datetime
import asyncio

import tornado.web
import tornado.httpserver
import tornado.netutil
from tornado.platform.asyncio import AsyncIOMainLoop

from autobahn.wamp import router
from autobahn.asyncio import wamp, websocket


# WAMP server
class MyBackendComponent(wamp.ApplicationSession):
    def onConnect(self):
        self.join(u"realm1")

    @asyncio.coroutine
    def onJoin(self, details):
        def utcnow():
            now = datetime.datetime.utcnow()
            return six.u(now.strftime("%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%SZ"))

        reg = yield from self.register(utcnow, 'com.timeservice.now')


# HTTP server
class MainHandler(tornado.web.RequestHandler):
    def get(self):
        self.write("Hello, world!")


tornado_app = tornado.web.Application(
    [
        (r"/", MainHandler),
    ],
)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    router_factory = router.RouterFactory()
    session_factory = wamp.RouterSessionFactory(router_factory)
    session_factory.add(MyBackendComponent())
    transport_factory = websocket.WampWebSocketServerFactory(session_factory,
                                                             debug=True,
                                                             debug_wamp=True)

    AsyncIOMainLoop().install()

    tornado_app.listen(80, "127.0.0.1")

    loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
    coro = loop.create_server(transport_factory, "127.0.0.1", 8080)
    server = loop.run_until_complete(coro)

    try:
        loop.run_forever()
    except KeyboardInterrupt:
        pass
    finally:
        server.close()
        loop.close()
```

Question: **Is there the Right Way to make autobahn-wamp and tornado handlers listen on the same port?**
My initial idea was to implement some kind of socket.socket wrapper and dispatch incoming messages there but it turned out to be awfully messy. I don't want to use any external proxies because the backend should be portable as much as possible.
Also I'm not asking anybody to implement it for me(but of course you can if you want to!) - only to know if somebody have already done something similar before diving into autobahn/tornado code.
Thanks in advance!
PS: Sorry for my poor English - it's not my mother tongue.

Comment: How would the OS know which application to deliver the packets to?

Comment: AutobahnPython comes with an example for combining WAMP/Twisted and TwistedWeb on 1 port. Essentially, it lets TwistedWeb serve HTTP(S), but forward a subpath, e.g. `/ws` to AutobahnPython for WebSocket/WAMP. Maybe there is a similar approach possible with Tornado: let Tornado accept and serve HTTP, but write some "resource" thing that would upon receiving a HTTP request for `/ws` create a WebSocket/WAMP protocol instance and hence forward bytes at TCP level.

Comment: @JonathonReinhart There is only one application with different handlers. WebSocket connection is established on top of existing tcp request-responce HTTP connection with handshake message AFAIK. So after the "upgrade" HTTP message has been recieved by Tornado all incoming data should be interpreted as WebSocket messages and go to appropriate ws:// handler. And it does go to native Tornado websocket.WebSocketHandler if you specify respective endpoint in tornado_app. But Tornado doesn't have WAMP implementations so I have to use autobahn somehow.

Comment: @oberstet Yeah, I saw that example. Looks like this is the simplest way.